# How do I get the knee to bend?

Tags: bones

[image]
I'd like to bend the knees when I move the control bone. They are stiff, how can I fix that? It's not seeable in the pictures but there is a pole bone on the right side.

Comment: Take a look the lessons from BlenderGuru. There everything is described in detail. https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: are you only moving your ctrl bone on the y axis? You need to push it upwards too. To somewhat "compress" the bones, then the knee will start moving outwards. if this also doesnt work, check your IK chain length.

Comment: I was also moving it upwards. I wanted to mention that but I forgot... Here the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5800" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5800/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you linked the bone and your mesh? if so have you selected automatic weights when doing so? ( just the way I like to do it )

If you don't want to use automatic weights, just select the parts in the mesh, in the editor mode, and the bone, then link them.
( I'm not a pro, please take what I say with a grain of salt, it might not work! )